# How can I fix problems with my C# Audio to Text program

Tags: c#, audio, artificial-intelligence

I have problems in my MainWindow.cs to convert an audio file to text.
In my .wav I said: "Hello my Name is Paul".
It recognized "Mir Rohre". This is wrong. How can I fix problems. I want to create an application that does not edit the audio files online. I want it to calculate it locally.

MainWindow.cs

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.AudioFormat;
using NAudio.Wave;
using System.IO;

namespace AudioToTextConverter
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BrowseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Filter = "Audio Files|*.m4a;*.wav;*.mp3;*.flac;*.ogg|All Files|*.*";
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                AudioFilePath.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void ConvertButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string audioFilePath = AudioFilePath.Text;

            // NAudio: Open the audio file and convert it to WAV format
            var reader = new AudioFileReader(audioFilePath);
            var waveFormat = new WaveFormat(reader.WaveFormat.SampleRate, 16, 1); // Verwenden Sie die gleiche Abtastrate wie die Eingabe
            var resampler = new MediaFoundationResampler(reader, waveFormat);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = resampler.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    stream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
                recognizer.SetInputToAudioStream(stream, new SpeechAudioFormatInfo(waveFormat.SampleRate, AudioBitsPerSample.Sixteen, AudioChannel.Mono));

                // Verwenden Sie die DictationGrammar, um beliebige Sprache zu erkennen
                System.Speech.Recognition.Grammar dictationGrammar = new DictationGrammar();
                recognizer.LoadGrammar(dictationGrammar);

                System.Speech.Recognition.RecognitionResult result = recognizer.Recognize();

                if (result != null)
                {
                    ConvertedText.Text = result.Text;
                }
                else
                {
                    ConvertedText.Text = "Keine Sprache erkannt.";
                }

                recognizer.UnloadAllGrammars();
                recognizer.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Audio .wav:[Audio File on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hyu-FVSd8mFCmFTxy5AONnDKCauObZ7_/view?usp=sharing)

Output in App:
[App Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oeak.png)

I asked ChatGPT. But he could not help me.